# CSS: Bootstrap menu item right align

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I added a menu item called Registration and am trying to have it right aligned using custom.css. (I can't post a screenshot of it due to lack of reputation as this is my first post here)

The following is what I currently have in custom.css

```css
li.nav-registration {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
      <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Music" asp-action="Index">Music</a></li>
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Video">Video</a></li>
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="nav-registration"><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Registration">Registration</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The styles in custom.css are being properly styled. However, the 'Registration' menu is still not being right aligned - any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: seems like it's aligned to the right for me... https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/qjbdvg

Comment: @MichaelCoker yeh it's being styled for me too but the menu is still aligned to the left even after hard refreshing the page. Anything else you can think of thats stopping the menu from aligning to the right?

Comment: Do you want the text inside the list to be right aligned or the entire menu to be on the right of the screen?

Comment: @PatrikAffentranger I just want the text (Registration) inside the nav list to be right aligned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you will have to create 2 separate `navbar` elements. One for `About, Music, Video, Contact` and one for `Registration`:

```html
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Music" asp-action="Index">Music</a></li>
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Video">Video</a></li>
        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="nav-registration"><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Registration">Registration</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

You are not stating if you are using Bootstrap v3 or v4. Either way, the solution is the same that you will have to separate the 2 "navs". It's just the classes that you need that will change based on the bootstrap version.

Bootstrap 3 example:
https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Bootstrap 4 navbar code:
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#supported-content

Comment: Using Bootstrap 3 and yes your solution worked, thanks.

Comment: This works for me in order to have the menu items right aligned: <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1 nav justify-content-end">